# How can I extract birth years from birth dates in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

the input of my file is as follows

```
Koe par 22-10-1992 nep
Ler par 10-04-2000 sis
```

I'd like the output to be as follows

```
Koe par 1992 nep
Ler par 2000 is
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about `awk` but this `sed` works:

```
sed -E 's/dates/years/;s/[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-//g' birthdates 
id  birthyears  pref
Koe 1992  nep
Ler 2000  sis
```

If it is important to keep the columns neatly aligned, do:

```
sed -E 's/dates/years/;s/[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-([0-9]{4})/\1      /g' birthdates 
id  birthyears  pref
Koe 1992        nep
Ler 2000        sis
```

Where `birthdates` is this file:

```
id  birthdates  pref
Koe 22-10-1992  nep
Ler 10-04-2000  sis
```

---

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{if (NR==1) {print $0} else {split($2,result,"-"); print $1 " " result[3] " " $3}}' birthdates
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work:

```
sed 's/birthdates/birthyears/g; s/[0-9]\{1,2\}-[0-9]\{1,2\}-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1/g' < myfile.txt > output.txt
```

Example:

```
ron@ron:~$ cat myfile.txt 
id  birthdates  pref
Koe 22-10-1992  nep
Ler 10-04-2000  sis
ron@ron:~$ sed 's/birthdates/birthyears/g; s/[0-9]\{1,2\}-[0-9]\{1,2\}-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1/g' < myfile.txt > output.txt 
ron@ron:~$ cat output.txt 
id  birthyears  pref
Koe 1992  nep
Ler 2000  sis
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$(NF-1),$NF}' FS="[ -]" inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/(.+)[ ]+(.+)[ ]+([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-)([0-9]{4})[ ]+(.+)/\1 \2 \4 \5/'
```